Can I tell docker-compose to give a container access to apple M3 silicone like I can with an NVIDIA gpu?
I'm deploying an LLM as a microservice implemented in a docker container, and I'm trying to increase the resources to it by configuring it in my docker-compose file.
I'm using a Mac with a M3 chip, and I'd like to add the "capability" of the M3 to my container in the docker-compose file like the following (paraphrased) example from the docker official website:
services:
  test:
    image: my_image
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]

As mentioned I'm not using nvidia, but I'd like to do something like this for my apple M3 silicon chip.
I tried looking through various google searches, and wasn't able to find an example that fit my hardware.

You can't at the moment
